# Need help in parsing json string in SQL stored procedure and accessing its attribute's value

Tags: sql, json, stored-procedures

I want to parse json string coming from request, extract particular information from that string and then based on that information need to call relevant update statements.

In java service it would be bit tedious to do this task as need to send each parameter separately and call relevant update statements.

If I can do the same task in stored procedure then it would be efficient. is there any way I can parse this same json string in a SQL stored procedure and update corresponding fields of tables by value of related attributes ?

Sample json string is -

```
{"category1":{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}}
```

this I want to send as a parameter of stored procedure

and I want to call update statement to update fields of related table with value1 and value2.

How can I parse these values in stored procedure from json string that I pass as a parameter to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this would be better off as a comment but I currently don't have that many rep points..

With that said you could try [comma-schema](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/).

I noticed [this article](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/04/08/json-parsing-in-mysql-using-common-schema/) using it.. I think you could use it to do the same.

Basically create data like the above article then update as needed

Comment: It is good solution but as I am using SQL Server and common-schema is not supported in SQL Server. Is there any other solution for parsing in SQL Server ?

Comment: @yashaswi after some searching.. i came up with [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) article. you should try it out.. seems to work for me..

Comment: [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) you gave is not meeting my requirement as I do not want to generate any table from parsing json string. I just want a function that accepts json string and attribute as a parameter and return value of that attribute from json string. I am not so good in pl/sql. Can you please suggest any logic how can I implement it?

Comment: @yashaswi hmm... the created parseJSON() is a storedprocedure..  first you  create it.. then try to run it.. ````as select * from parseJSON(yourjsonstringhere)```` You should get a table (but it's not created!!!) so if you want.. you should do.. something like 
````select StringValue from parseJSON(yourjsonstringhere) where NAME='yourattributename'; ````

Comment: select StringValue from parseJSON(yourjsonstringhere) where NAME='yourattributename'; worked but still as my requirement is bit complex can I give path for attribute ? for example I have json string as -    {"category1":{"staff1":{"staffId":"1","staffName":"name2"}},{"staff2":{"staffId":"2","staffName":"value2"}},{"staff3":{"staffId":"3","staffName":"value3"}}} now I want to access category1.staff2.staffName. I tried with parent_ID, object_ID, sequenceNo but it did not work to access StringValue this way.

Comment: I tried with select StringValue from parseJSON(yourjsonstringhere) where NAME='staffName' and element_id = 2; but element_id or parent_id would not be identical for each case and json data string will not always match standard schema and it depends on user input. say for above case if user is not entering staff1 details then json string would be like -  {"category1":{"staff2":{"staffId":"2","staffName":"name2"}},{"staff3":{"staffId":"3","staffName":"value3"}}} so for both the cases I am not able to decide by giving element_id in condition would always work

Comment: your json string you gave is not a proper json string. please give me an appropriate one

Comment: also.. if you look at the article I linked there is also a toXML part.. so.. if you do something like.. parseJSON then toXML you should get an xml.. which i believe is supported in sqlserver..

Comment: Thanks for the help. finally I got the solution for this hierarchical path we can trace attributes by comparing parent_ID with object_ID of parent. something like this - (select StringValue from dbo.parseJSON(@data) where name = 'staffName' and parent_ID in (select Object_ID from dbo.parseJSON(@data) where name = 'staff2'))

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can use JSON in a Stored procedure. This is a best way to make your DB closer to REST APIs. Your Stored procedure can have input and output both as JSON. It is just that you have to put efforts in writing a good stored procedure. rather than exposing a random access to API/user for querying it directly

here is one of the example:

```
DECLARE @out VARCHAR(max) =''
EXEC csdm.your_sp 
    @input = <your_JSON_string>,
    @output = @out OUTPUT
    SELECT @out
```

Now to achieve this write your SP as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.your_sp
    @input VARCHAR(max),
    @output VARCHAR(max) OUTPUT
AS 
PRINT 'PROC_START : dbo.your_sp'
-- Declare variables as needed
DECLARE @sp_output VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @json_category VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @json_category VARCHAR(max)

-- Validate JSON
IF(ISJSON(@input) = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sp_output = '{"status":"Error","errorTitle":"Invalid Input JSON","errorMessage":"JSON sent as input is Incorrect, please verify and fix"}'
    
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Process JSON if valid JSON provided
    -- Option 1
    INSERT INTO myTable
        (Field1, Field2)
    VALUES
    (
        SELECT [VALUE] FROM OPENJSON(@op, '$.category1') where [KEY] = 'field1',
        SELECT [VALUE] FROM OPENJSON(@op, '$.category1') where [KEY] = 'field1'
    )

    SET @sp_output = '{"status":"Success", "message":"Record updated successfully"}'


    -- Option 2 : Can have more validation for the data
    SELECT @json_category = VALUE FROM OpenJson (@input, '$') WHERE [Key] = 'category1'
    SELECT @json_field_value = VALUE FROM OpenJson (@json_category, '$') WHERE [Key] = 'field1'

    IF(@json_category IS NOT NULL OR @json_category <> '') AND (@json_field_value IS NOT NULL OR @json_field_value <> '')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO myTable
        (Field1, Field2)
        VALUES
        (
            SELECT [VALUE] FROM OPENJSON(@op, '$.category1') where [KEY] = 'field1',
            SELECT [VALUE] FROM OPENJSON(@op, '$.category1') where [KEY] = 'field1'
        )
        
        SET @sp_output = '{"status":"Success", "message":"Record updated successfully"}'

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @sp_output = '{"status":"Error","errorTitle":"Blank/Missing Input provided","errorMessage":"Critical / Mandatory data is missing in the input JSON"}'
    END

END


-- Build Output or Error response
SET @output = @sp_output
PRINT 'PROC_END : dbo.your_sp'
RETURN
GO
```

This is just a sample to show how to use JSON, you can do a lot more in this additionally